# R How to see variable importance plot for an ensemble_model (H2O)?

Tags: r, h2o, ensemble-learning

Does anyone know has to see variable importance plot for an ensemble model built in H2O using R?

This code h2o.varimp_plot(ensemble_model) returns an error

```
In max(tvi$coefficients) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: The ensembl is a machine learning models, the variable importances are not calculated. it's not so straightforward. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349631/how-to-describe-most-important-features-of-ensemble-model-as-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently unimplemented, but you can follow the progress here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5137